# How to check if a data point is within the boundary of a cluster or not

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

Suppose I have done clustering (using 3 features) and got 4 clusters, training on a set of data points.

Now in production I will be getting a different set of  data points, and based on the values of the features of that data point, I need to know if it falls in the pre-defined cluster that I made earlier or not. This is not doing clustering but rather finding if a point falls within a pre-defined cluster.

How do I find whether the point is in a cluster?

Do I need to run linear regression to find the equation of the boundary  covering the cluster?

Comment: could you give the sample code that you tried?

Comment: Please define your problem more clearly.  Do you need to know whether the point falls within *any* of the three clusters, or whether it's within a specified cluster?  Do you need to determine whether it's within the convex closure of a cluster, or simply get the cluster number to which it would be assigned?  The last of these, of course, is simply KMeans scoring.

Comment: Define *boundary*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to your question. The way new point is assigned to a cluster **is a property of the cluster itself**. Thus the crucial thing is "what is the clustering procedure used in the first place". Each well defined clustering method (in mathematical sense) provides you with the whole input space partitioning, not just finite training set. Such techniques include k-means, GMM, ...

However, there are exceptions - clustering methods which are simply heuristics, and not valid optimization problems. For example if you use hierarchical clustering there is no partitioning of the space, thus you cannot correctly assign new point to any cluser, and you are left with dozens of equally correct, heuristic methods which will do something - but you cannot say which one is correct. These heuristics include:

- "closest point heuristics", which is essentialy equivalent of training 1-NN on your clusters
- "build a valid model heuristics" which is a generalization of the above where you fit some classifier (of your choice) to mimic the original clustering (and select its hyperparameters through cross validation).
- "what would happen if I re-run the clustering", if you can re-run the clustering from the previous solution you can simply check what cluster it falls into given previous clustering as a starting point.
- ...